# Calderon-Zygmund Operator Associated to Zero Kernel

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

We say that a Calderon-Zygmund operator (CZO) $T:L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (i.e. a bounded linear operator) is associated to a CZ kernel $K:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\Delta$ ($\Delta$ denotes the diagonal subset) if the following holds: for $f\in L_{c}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ fixed, for almost everywhere (a.e.) $x\notin\text{supp}(f)$,
    $$Tf(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}K(x,y)f(y)dy$$

Suppose that a CZO $T:L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is associated the kernel $K(x,y)=0$. In the hint for Question 2 in the Exercises section of [Tao's Lecture Notes 4](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247a.1.06f/), he suggests that we can show $T$ is given by pointwise multiplication by a bounded function (i.e. $Tf=bf$, where $b\in L^{\infty}$) by observing that the set function
    $$E\mapsto \langle{T(\chi_{E}),\chi_{E}}\rangle$$
is an absolutely continuous measure and then applying the Radon-Nikodym theorem. I see where the Radon-Nikodym theorem gives us a measurable function $b$ such that
    $$\langle{Tf,f}\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}b\left|f\right|^{2},\quad\forall f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$
by the boundedness of $T$, the density of simple functions in $L^{2}$, and the linearity of the integral. But I am failing to see (perhaps very foolishly) why we can readily deduce that $Tf=bf$ for all $f\in L^{2}$. I believe I can obtain the desired result using a different argument, as shown below; but I would still like to see how to make Tao's suggestion work. Does anyone have a suggestion?

---

Let $g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ have compact support. For any cube $Q\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$,
    $$T(\chi_{Q}g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}K(x,y)\chi_{Q}(y)g(y)dy=0 \quad \text{ a.e. } x\notin\overline{Q}$$
and
    $$T(\chi_{Q^{c}}g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}K(x,y)\chi_{Q^{c}}(y)g(y)dy=0 \quad \text{ a.e. } x\in Q^{o}$$
Since $T(\chi_{Q}g)=T(g)-T(\chi_{Q^{c}}g) \text{ a.e. }$, we conclude that
    $$T(\chi_{Q}g)(x)=\chi_{Q}(x)(Tg)(x) \quad \text{ a.e. }$$
Since the collection of all cubes with rational vertices is countable and finite linear combinations of the characteristic functions of such cubes are dense in $L^{2}$, the boundedness of $T$ yields
    $$T(fg)=f(Tg) \quad\text{ a.e. },\qquad\forall f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$$

To see that $T$ is given by pointwise multiplication by a bounded function $b$, let $B_{j}$ be the ball centered at the origin of radius $j$. Observe that if $j'\geq j$, then $\chi_{B_{j}}\chi_{B_{j'}}=\chi_{B_{j}}$ and therefore
    $$T(\chi_{B_{j}})=T(\chi_{B_{j}}\chi_{B_{j'}})=\chi_{B_{j}}T(B_{j'}) \quad \text{ a.e. }$$
by our previous result. Thus, we can define almost everywhere a measurable function $b$ by
    $$b(x)=T(\chi_{B_{j}})(x), \quad x\in B_{j}$$
For an $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, let $f_{j}=f\chi_{B_{j}}$.Then by the continuity of $T$ and a.e. convergence $f_{j}\rightarrow f$
    $$T(f)=\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}T(f_{j})=\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}bf_{j}=bf \quad \text{ a.e. }$$
To see that $b$ is bounded, observe that
    $$\left\|T\right\|_{L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}}=\sup_{f\in L^{2}}\left\|Tf\right\|_{L^{2}}=\sup_{f\in L_{c}^{2}}\left\|bf\right\|_{L^{2}}=\left\|b\right\|_{L^{\infty}}$$

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it was incorrect, as you pointed out. In general $\langle Sf,f\rangle=0$ for every $f$ does not imply $f=0$ (e.g. rotation by $90$ degrees in $\mathbb R^2$). Selfadjointness would work for sure, but maybe some condition that you have on the CZ kernel can help you? If they weren't notes by Tao I would suggest that the author might have done a mistake, but in this case I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: After talking to a peer, I believe I know how to make the hint work. See my answer posted below. My initial confusion came from the fact that the simplicity of the hint suggested to me that the solution was more trivial than it actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the first part of the alternative solution I gave in my question post, we have that

$$T(\chi_{E\cap F})=T(\chi_{E}\chi_{F})=\chi_{F}T(\chi_{E}) \quad \text{a.e.}$$

for all measurable sets $E$ and $F$ with $\left|E\right|,\left|F\right|<\infty$. Following the hint, we can show that

$$\langle{T(\chi_{A}),\chi_{A}}\rangle=\int b\chi_{A},\quad\forall A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n},\left|A\right|<\infty$$

By Lebesgue differentiation theorem,

\begin{align*}
\left|b(x)\right|\leq\limsup_{{Q\ni x}\atop{\left|Q\right|\rightarrow 0}}\left|Q\right|^{-1}\left|\int_{Q}b\right|&\leq\limsup_{{Q\ni x}\atop{\left|Q\right|\rightarrow 0}}\left|Q\right|^{-1}\left\|T\chi_{Q}\right\|_{L^{2}}\left|Q\right|^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left\|T\right\|_{L^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}}\quad \text{a.e.}
\end{align*}
by Cauchy-Schwarz. Whence, $b\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Whence,

$$\langle{T\chi_{E},\chi_{F}}\rangle=\int_{E\cap F}b=\int b\chi_{E}\chi_{F}$$

By density of simple functions, linearity, and $L^{2}$ boundedness of $T$, we conclude that

$$\langle{Tf,g}\rangle=\langle{bf,g}\rangle,\quad\forall f,g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}),$$

which implies that $Tf=bf$ a.e.